# Pop_up on checkbox selection

Tags: android, checkbox, popup

How can I display a  pop-up immediately a checkbox is checked in Android?

Answer (score 2):

```
CheckBox yourCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById( R.id.yourCheckBox );
yourCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
   {
      if (isChecked)
         {
            //call popup
         }
   }
});
```

You just need to declare a call back for the `CheckedChanged` Event on the text box and then fire your method that displays the popup